# How to ensure a successful compile using Git

Tags: git

I'm just starting out with Git but haven't actually used it in a team. The biggest question I have yet to answer is how to use Git in such a way to ensure that my main branch compiles successfully 100% of the time. Realistically I know that that is not possible.

From what I understand, each developer grabs a copy of the repository, makes changes locally and periodically commits changes. Multiple branches can end up getting created throughout the week but once or twice a week I'd like to have a compile on my main branch.

I assume that each developer is responsible for merging branches into the main branch and that the project leader performs a compile on the code along the main branch. Is this the general flow of how things typically work in a team collaborating with Git? Does the project leader have to notify all the other developers to make all their commits by say 3:00 pm on Wednesday because a compile will be made at that time? or does the project leader not need to tell developers when to perform their final commits and just assumes that the main branch is always in a state that it will compile without problems?

I guess my difficulty in understanding how to use Git effectively is how all developers remain synchronized by the time you want to perform a major compile once or twice a week.

Comment: Two points: a) build automation. Don't have a major compile once or twice a week. Have it automated as often as feasible.  b) release branches: close to release, make a release branch that no one is committing to freely any longer

Comment: How often should a release branch be done under normal circumstances?

Comment: Once per release. How often do you release?

Comment: Once every two weeks. This is based on a 2 week sprint using Scrum.

Comment: Scrum (I think) implies integrated testing throughout the sprint. So you should be having working builds almost all the time, I guess. But yes, once you think it can be released, make a release branch (and later a release tag) to achieve "code freeze" without shutting down everyone who still wants to commit non-release work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are predefined workflows that can help you to get inspiration for a good git workflow. [git-flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) is the most well known.

It doesn't mean you have to do it exactly like that, but it can give you guidance how to implement a release branch, how to deal with hot-fixes and more.

Another well known workflow is [github flow](http://scottchacon.com/2011/08/31/github-flow.html), which uses a much simpler approach. It just has a development branch, and everyone works on feature branches, which get merged back in when ready. They also use continuous deployment, so they get rapid feedback when a build breaks.

Comment: git-flow looks nice. It mentions "Feature branches typically exist in developer repos only, not in origin." - Why would you NOT want to store your features in the origin, especially since it's on the server? After all, if your local machine crashes and you don't have a backup, you're screwed. But if you push all your work to the server, you can recover from a crash.

Comment: Pushing is about sharing history, not backing up commits. Though it serves as a backup, it's not a replacement for good backups. feature-branches are typically short-lived and will be removed after they've been merged in. Also it makes it easier to rebase the feature branch, because you know no-one has comitted on it.

Answer (score 1):

Tools like https://travis-ci.org/ help they always try and compile and test new branches and master.

Other ways that help are pre commit hooks which either compile or run some tests or something before commiting. it makes the commit process slower but wont allow a commit which has a file which either wont compile or fails a test.